# 18.04.1 steam says I can't make a partition on a drive without exec but I edited fstab

Tags: 18.04, steam, fstab, executable

I have previously edited fstab successfully to automount my extra HDDs, and I've updated it to include exec permission

```
rw,exec,user,auto,fmask=0177,dmask=0077,uid=1000
```

When I try to make a new installation point in Steam, it still says my HDD doesn't have exec permission. Anyone know why?

(edit) I also did a hard reboot after editing fstab
(edit) Put "exec" after "user", added guid=1000, added suid, nothing has worked.

Comment: Unbelievable. Can't even answer my own question.
Steam absolutely will not install to NTFS drives. I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I found the fix:

First run this command (change `sdb1` to your disk):

```
ntsfix /dev/sdb1
```

Second, in `/etc/fstab` add this:\

```
UUID=7A9XXXXXXX /mnt/Data ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```